# Codeigniter application displays blank page on localhost ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, codeigniter, ubuntu

I am getting blank in ubuntu localhost. The same application is working fine on windows OS. I am not getting any error only a blank page is displayed. I have also given 777 permission to the folder. Please help

Comment: Too broad make sure the controllers filenames and classes etc are ucfirst as case sensitive as said here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: First, [enable errors displaying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587413/codeigniter-displays-a-blank-page-instead-of-error-messages).

Comment: as per suggested by you i made the changes but no luck - @wolfgang1983.  My error reporting is also enable. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your http and php logs tell you? Are you running SELinux?

Comment: i further debug it and found that in index.php require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php'; this line is causing the issue as i put echo before this line it gets excuted but no after this line. And is [Sat Feb 25 21:16:25.503671 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1191] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21 configured -- resuming normal operations in apache logs - @Brian Ramsey

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple factors:

1) Check with you config file. How you define your base URL etc OR their is chances of you calling your controller in wrong way. This might be help you [CodeIgniter - Default controller not loading automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367539/codeigniter-default-controller-not-loading-automatically)

2) There is also possibilities something missing (dependency) in your LAMP stack. Just reinstall your LAMP environment with 'tasksel' package installer. It will install your all LAMP stack with all dependencies.

Comment: The second suggestion worked for me. I used tasksel and install the LAMP stack. You save my day. Thanks @Ashish Tiwari KUDOS :-). Thanks to others too who tried to help me out